# Copying Dates from one Excel sheet to another Excel Sheet?

Tags: excel-2007

I am trying to copy a date from one excel sheet formated as so: "dd MONTH YYYY" (example: "19 January 2012"), this date is got using the =now() function.

I want to copy this date into a second excel sheet in a mid-sentence position as such:

"Today is 19 January 2012" I am using the following formula in the cell:

="Today is "& 'Sheet1'!c3&" the weather is fine"

However the sentence returns like this:

Today is 40927.4598005787 the weather is fine

How do I get this to show the date in the same format as sheet one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a format with `TEXT()`

```
  ="Today is " & TEXT(sheet1!c3, "dd mmmm yyyy") &" the weather is fine"
```